# System Modeler 4 on Mac X El Capitan does not work

Tags: mac-os-x, ccompilerdriver, system-modeler

I have installed the Mac version of System Modeler 4 in a MacBook Pro with OS X El Capitan  . Also the Coder has been installed version 7 . But the System modeler can not find the C ++ compiler not is able to choose from the Preference tab.

I am using version 7 of the Xcode.  Notice that the Download tab is no longer available under the Preference and also there is no way to choose the compiler from the Verify.

Please, help me with specific instruction to add the compiler. Wolfram shows a [page](https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/compiler-mac/) with a limited instructions but can not name much from it

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you started Xcode and agreed to the licence terms after the latest update? This is always something I forget, and has fixed problems for me before.

Comment: Thank you.. I did,, but I found out that the problem is that I wan using version 3 and does not detect the Chang compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemModeler 3 and it's really old and doesn't support recent versions of Xcode (you need a Xcode version that use the C++ standard library from gcc by default and not libc++).

You need to upgrade SystemModeler to at least version 4.0 for it to work with Xcode 7.  Apple changed the requirements on signed applications in a patch release of El Capitan so it no longer considers SystemModeler to be correctly signed (this will be fixed in the next release). To get around it you can right-click (or ctrl + left click) on SystemModeler and select open. You should then get a dialog with an option to let it run anyway, it remembers your choice so you will only need to use this procedure once.